# Creating a static variable in C

Tags: c

With `static` in `C` one can keep a `stack` variable around, even after the creating function exists.

In this case however,

```
void static_func() {
    static int var = 1;
    var += 1;
}
```

I can access `var` outside of the `static_func()` and return its value. Let's assume `static_func()` is called three times in the `main()`, then the value of `var` is 3.

However, it is set to `1` every time the function is executed. Why do I still get the value 3?!

Comment: `static` and _static_ variables mean something different.

Comment: "However, it is set to `1` every time the function is executed." Why? Because your compiler contains a bug?

Comment: And where is your `stack`? This is no keyword in C, nor does C require a _stack_. And typical implementations which use a _stack_ don't store `static` variables (which are a subset of _static_ variables) on the stack.

Comment: @MikeCAT I do not hope so! ;)

Comment: After three calls, the value in `var` is 4, not 3.  You can't access `var` outside the function.  You could return (a copy of) its value.  If you returned a pointer to the variable, it could be indirectly accessible outside the function, but not otherwise.  As written, you have no way of doing anything useful with `var`. If you had `static int static_func(void) { static int var = 1; return ++var; }` then you'd have a monotonic counter that's not resettable except by overflow (which is undefined behaviour, which is bad).

Comment: No, you *cannot* access your static local variable `var` outside function `static_func()`.  Local variables have *no linkage*, regardless of their storage class.

Comment: "I can access var outside of the static_func()" - If that is true, **instantly** `rm -f $YOUR_COMPILER_BINARY_WITH_PATH`. And `(1 + 3 * 1) == 4`, not `3`.

Comment: @Olaf, I don't understand "(1 + 3 * 1) == 4, not 3", it's indeed 4

Comment: @ForceBru: I did not use a pocket calculator, but I'm pretty confident the expression evaluates `true`. OP seems to think three calls incrementiong from `1` yields `3`. What is not clear about my comment?

Comment: @Olaf, oops, now I got it :P no problem

Comment: @Olaf yeah, I made a mistake there... It should be four! Bottom line of my question was why it does not get set back to one every time the function is called...

Comment: @ForceBru Thought about `var` being `3` or `4`.  Given the trivial code, perhaps a compiler can optimize out `var` and so it has no value and does not even exist?  IOW can a compile simple do `void static_func() { ; }`?  Hmmm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you say `static int var = 1;`, this variable is created *and* initialized. This can happen *only once*, otherwise you're gonna flood your memory with useless duplicates since this variable will stay alive during whole program runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The initial value of a `static` variable is only applied once at program startup.  It doesn't happen each time the function is entered.